# Thousands of concurrent http requests in node

Tags: linux, node.js, concurrency

I have a list of thousands of URLs. I want to get a health check (healt.php) with an http request.

This is my problem:

I've wrote an application in node. It makes the requests in a pooled way. I use a variable to control how many concurrent connections I open. 300, ie.
One by one, each request is so fast, no more than 500ms.

But when I run the application, the result is:

```
$ node agent.js

200ms   url1.tld
250ms   url4.tld
400ms   url2.tld
530ms   url8.tld
800ms   url3.tld
...
2300ms  urlN.tld
...
30120ms urlM.tld
```

It seems that there is a limit in concurrency. When I execute

```
$ ps axo nlwp,cmd | grep node
```

The result is:

```
6 node agent.js
```

There are 6 threads to manage all concurrent connections. I found an evn variable to control concurrency in node: UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE

```
$ UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=300 node agent.js

200ms   url1.tld
210ms   url4.tld
220ms   url2.tld
240ms   url8.tld
400ms   url3.tld
...
800ms  urlN.tld
...
1010ms urlM.tld
```

The problem is still there, but the results are much better. With the ps command:

```
$ ps axo nlwp,cmd | grep node

132 node agent.js
```

Next step: Looking in the source code of node, I've found a constant in deps/uv/src/unix/threadpool.c:

```
#define MAX_THREADPOOL_SIZE 128
```

Ok. I've changed that value to 2048, compiled and installed node and run once the command

```
$ UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=300 node agent.js
```

All seems ok. Response times are not incrementing gradually. But when I try with a bigger concurrency number the problema appears. But this time it's not related to the number of threads, because with the ps command I see there are enough of them.

I tried to write the same application in golang, but the results are the same. The time is increasing gradually.

So, my question is: Where is the concurrence limit? memory and cpu load and bandwith are not out of bounds. And I tuned sysctl.conf and limits.conf to avoid some limits (files, ports, memory, ...).

Comment: While not an answer, you may consider using the `cluster` module to utilise all available CPUs so that the work is better distributed on your hardware. Context switching may also play a role here, although I would not think it would cause such major delays.

Answer (score 2):

You may be throttled by http.globalAgent's `maxSockets`. Depending on whether you're using http or https, see if this fixes your problem:

```
require('http').globalAgent.maxSockets = Infinity;
require('https').globalAgent.maxSockets = Infinity;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `request` or `request-promise`  you can set the pool size:

```
  request({
    url: url,
    json: true,
    pool: {maxSockets: Infinity},
    timeout: 2000
  })
```

More info here: https://github.com/request/request